# Reply as Anonymous(Unknown User) in SharePoint Community forum?

Tags: xslt-list-view-web-part, community-site, community

I have a SharePoint Community Site. Our Management believes users are not giving genuine replies due to lack of anonymity. So we need to provide a functionality to "Reply as anonymous" in a community discussion?

I tried the following.

1. Tried to use JS link "OnPostRender" to add a button as "Reply as Anonymous" using jquery and tried to use JSOM to save the reply. I am new to JS link and it's not moving forward.
2. XSL Link: I am yet to explore this. Even if I can put button using this, it mayn't be easy to save the reply.
3. I also looked at this answer. [Add item to list anonymously (not as anonymous user)?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37053/add-item-to-list-anonymously-not-as-anonymous-user)

But I am looking for answer using JSOM.